# CLNDR - How to get Today, Tomorrow and Current Month event list and count and print that information to separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, calendar, underscore.js

Hi I'm using **CLNDR** and trying to get today, tomorrow and this month event list and event count information into separate div, I did try various things but couldn't find a better solution, can anyone, please help me with this. below code is for reference.

```js
doneRendering: function() {
                // make a moment object representing today
                var target = moment();
                var tommorow = target.add(1,'days');
                var eventsTommorow =[];

                    if(this.options.multiDayEvents) {

                        eventsTommorow = $.makeArray( $(this.options.events).filter( function() {
                            // filter the dates down to the ones that match.
                            return ( ( tommorow.isSame(this._clndrStartDateObject, 'day') || tommorow.isAfter(this._clndrStartDateObject, 'day') ) &&
                            ( tommorow.isSame(this._clndrEndDateObject, 'day') || tommorow.isBefore(this._clndrEndDateObject, 'day') ) );
                        }) );

                    } else {
                        eventsTommorow = $.makeArray( $(this.options.events).filter( function() {
                            // filter the dates down to the ones that match.
                            return this._clndrDateObject.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == dateString;
                        }) );
                    }


                    if(eventsTommorow.length) {
                        console.log(eventsTommorow.length);
                        var newNum = eventsTommorow.length < 10 ? "0" + eventsTommorow.length : eventsTommorow.length;
                        return $('.td-emp-count.tdTommorow').text(newNum);
                    }
                }
            },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please indicate what problem you have encountered with this - for instance, is it working, if not, what error are you getting? Simply stating that you couldn't find a better solution is not nearly as helpful to others willing to help.

Comment: please see the answer section. i can not explain here due to character limitation

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my problem is I can not filter events and print them into separate div, I tried moment.js validation to get today event. but it didn;t work as expected. but finally I tried a simple method to get today, tomorrow and this month event count and it worked. but the problem is if a recurring event happens, let's say maternity leave start on 24th April to 30th may then I can not get between event counts. because I'm capturing CLNDR date, startDate, endDate there is no way to get between events count. please find the code

```js
doneRendering: function() {
  // make a moment object representing today

  var _self = this;

  function todayCount() {
    var totalDate = _.filter(_self.options.events, {
      date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });
    var totalStartDate = _.filter(_self.options.events, {
      startDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });
    var totalEndDate = _.filter(_self.options.events, {
      endDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    var newNum = (totalDate.length + totalStartDate.length + totalEndDate.length) < 10 ? "0" + (totalDate.length + totalStartDate.length + totalEndDate.length) : (totalDate.length + totalStartDate.length + totalEndDate.length);
    return newNum;
  }




  $('.td-emp-count.tdToday').text(todayCount());



},
```

This is a simple hack and I'm using underscore.js. but this way I cannot get actual today count, the reason is if a recurring leave happens it cannot get middle leave day as a count

eg:

### Sick leave

startDate = 24th April 2016

endDate = 28th April 2016

when I apply my simple hack to this, I can only get 24th April (Monday) as one count and 28th April (Friday) as another count but when I try to print Wednesday leave counts, it cannot get this day as a leave count,

I'm new to underscore.js but I really need to know how to print these variables into underscore.js template,

### Within template event count.

I can get the today (actual leave) count by using _.each() method and print them on into day itself like this one

```js
<% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
  <div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>">
    <div class="num"><%= day.day %></div>
    <% if (day.events.length) { %>
      <div class="eventsTitles">Leave : <strong><%= day.events.length %></strong></div>
        <% } %>
       <ul class="dayLeaveTypes">
         <% _.each(day.events, function(event) { %>
         <li title="<%= event.type %>" id="<%= event.type %>" style="color:<%= event.color %>;">&#9679;</li>
         <% }); %>
       </ul>
 </div>
<% }); %>
```

but I need to get this actual count (only specific day today or tomorrow) and print them into separate div, not within the calendar.

this is the whole idea i'm trying to solve. :)